# How do I specify the com+ server when registering a vb6 com+ application without using clireg?

Tags: vb6, wix, com+, clireg32

I've found lots of documentation on how to install com+ components with WiX or an exported msi from dcomcnfg but the problem with these approaches is I can't see where to specify the com+ server.

Currently we register the components with clireg and the -s switch which allows us to specify the com+ server like so:

```
clireg32.exe BLEH.VBR -s COMSERVER -t BLEH.TLB -d
```

This is messy to say the least and I've been trying to get this into some automated form of installation that doesn't involve calling a batch file full of clireg32 calls.

Currently WiX is the backbone of our packaging automation so a solution with WiX would be awesome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use the Wix3 ComPlus extensions? (Sorry, no on-line link, check the Wix3 docs for reference and samples), Or maybe you want to register your ComPlus application as a **SERVICE** which at the moment is not possible with those extensions.

Comment: Well I don't see anything in the complus elements that would take the place of the "-s COMSERVER" we're passing to clireg32, it would let me install and register the complus components but they wouldn't be pointed at their server.

Comment: Okey, so you want a Com Server PROXY, it that true?

Comment: I guess, I'm sorry, this is an ancient program developed in the 90's which we no longer have the source code for. I'm not really sure of the specifics in terminology, I've just been charged with creating an automated installer for it.